# Combine two geojson state zipcode files?

Tags: python, json, geojson, geopandas

I am working on a project where I need to use [US States Zip Code Data](https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON). I want to merge two geojson files while preserving the data in those files. geojson-merge `https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-merge` does this but I am hoping for a python based solution.

Each state has a separate *.json file. For example:

1. mt_montana_zip_codes_geo.min.json
2. nd_north_dakota_zip_codes_geo.min.json

   ```
   import json

   nd_boundary_file = r"C:\Data_ZipCodes_States\State-zip-code-GeoJSON-master" \
             r"\nd_north_dakota_zip_codes_geo.min.json"

   with open(nd_boundary_file, 'r') as f:
       nd_zipcode_boundary = json.load(f)

   mt_boundary_file = r"C:\\Data_ZipCodes_States\State-zip-code-GeoJSON-master" \
             r"\mt_montana_zip_codes_geo.min.json"

   with open(mt_boundary_file, 'r') as f:
       mt_zipcode_boundary = json.load(f)


   #This overwrote the mt_zipcode_boundary with the nd_zipcode_boundary into merged
   #merged = {**mt_zipcode_boundary, **nd_zipcode_boundary}

   #produced a file with two json objects one 'mt' and the other 'nd'
   data = {'mt': mt_zipcode_boundary, 'nd':nd_zipcode_boundary}

   #Also overwrote mt_zipcode_boundary
   mt_zipcode_boundary.update(nd_zipcode_boundary)
   ```

How would I write code to combine these two geojson files into a single file?

Comment: Do they have the same structure? As in columns.

Comment: @martinfleis Yes they have the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
import json

fc = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

with open("mt_montana_zip_codes_geo.min.json") as json_file:
    obj = json.load(json_file)
    fc['features'].extend(obj['features'])

with open("nd_north_dakota_zip_codes_geo.min.json") as json_file:
    obj = json.load(json_file)
    fc['features'].extend(obj['features'])

with open("merged.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(fc, outfile)
```

Comment: worked like a charm. I don't understand it, but I do appreciate you showing me working code. I'll need to figure this out...

Comment: fc is a dictionary where 'features' is a key and its value is a list. json.load reads data from a file, parses the data and returns a dictionary with the data. list.extend(list_to_add) adds the list_to_add elements to the end of the list. json.dump(fc, outfile) writes the fc dictionary to the outfile file.